# How do I render a progressive JPEG on a QWidget as it is being downloaded?

Tags: qt

With Qt, rendering a fully downloaded image on QWidget is fairly easy. However, I want to render a partially downloaded progressive jpg (or png) as it is being fetched.

Comment: Ok. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried interpreting partially fetched bytearray as a jpg image by rendering it using QPainter. That does not work until the entire bytearray gets fetched. I also tried looking up documentation on QImage, QPainter on clues to handle progressive jpg.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember only GIF format suitable for that purposes. And I not see way to do this with QT tools and libraries. Think you need found way to covert partialy downloaded (gif) image to QPixmap or QImage and show it.

Answer (score -1):

You can render the image on a QGraphicsView. For this purpose, you can write a QGraphicsItem which has two QImage pointers as member variables. One of them can be used as a buffer so that the newcoming bytes can be written into the buffer. The other image can be used for rendering. paint() function should be as below

```
painter->drawImage(0,0,*mRenderImage);
```